# How can I assign an auto-incrementing ID per group in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, grouping

I want to group my data by Name and Amount, each group that is returned must have a unique ID which increments per group in the data.

This is the relevant bit of code:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                data.GroupBy(x=> new {x.Name, x.Amount})
                    .Where(gp => gp.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(
                        gp =>
                            new Group
                            {
                                GroupData = gp.Select(el => new GroupItem
                                {
                                    Name = el.Name,
                                    Amount = el.Amount,
                                    GroupId = <missing>
                                })
                            }));
```

I have found several questions for adding an incremental ID for each row within a group, which resets per group, however I want the group to be something like this:

```
Group = {"bob", 145.20, 1},
        {"bob", 145.20, 1},
Group = {"steve", 120.00, 2},
        {"steve", 120.00, 2}..... etc
```

The only examples I have found where to do this are in SQL, whereas I need this for LINQ in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) overload that pass the index too:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    data.GroupBy(x=> new {x.Name, x.Amount})
        .Where(gp => gp.Count() > 1)
        .Select((gp, idx) =>
                new Group
                {
                    GroupData = gp.Select(el => new GroupItem
                    {
                        Name = el.Name,
                        Amount = el.Amount,
                        GroupId = idx
                    })
                }));
```